# Git How to set up dev, test and prod codebase

Tags: git, merge

I have a "prod" code base that has 2 features. 
I have a "test" code base that has 3 features. (2 features that prod has + 1 extra feature)
I have to work on feature 4 in my development environment.
My colleague has to work on feature 5 in his/her development environment.

Ok we both develop and push to 'test' everyday and pull again from "test" everyday and completed both features and merged with "test".
Very Easy now "test" has 5 features.
My local branch also has 5 features and my colleague's local branch also has all 5 features.

Now if i want to merge only the feature 5 to "prod", how do i do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pull specific commits related to feature 5 using git cherry pick

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.